# Apache complex regex crashing with 500 error

Tags: php, regex, apache, url, url-rewriting

I have been working with an existing website out company has running until I finish developing the new site.

I've been asked to add some additional functionality to booking pages that will automatically set a booking button based on passed parameters.

The existing working regex is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^.+-(\d+)\.accommodation$ property_detail.php?id=$1
```

Which works fine with the url like below and passes through the URL.

```
this-is-the-property-name.1234.accomodation
```

However as a quick shiv, I am trying to do the following:

```
this-is-the-property-name.1234.accomodation?override=true&start_date=2010-05-14&numbernights=2&sleeps=10&price=1012
```

The regex I came up with for this was:

```
RewriteRule ^.+-(\d+)\.accommodation\?override=(\w+)&start_date=(19|20)[0-9]{2}[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])&numbernights=(\d+)&sleeps=(\d+)&price=(\d+)$ property_detail.php?id=$1&override=$2&start_date=$3-$4-$5&numbernights=$6&sleeps=$7&price=$8
```

The regex is passing as valid in RegexBuddy - however it keeps causing a 500 error on the server.  Can anyone help me get my head around this one?

Comment: 500 means "Something is wrong! Look at the error log!". What does the error log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the first rewrite and append the query string with the [QSA] flag:

`RewriteRule ^.+-(\d+)\.accommodation$ property_detail.php?id=$1 [QSA]`

Comment: Brilliant answer!  Seems to work right away, I can see the variables now.  I'd vote up, but I don't have enough repuation yet :(

Comment: Glad you're happy - accept it if the answer if you're satisfied. Thanks!